# Multiline gnu regex

Tags: java, regex, gnu

I want to match an expression right after a new line. I´m using gnu.regexp and with flag REG_MULTILINE.
Here´s the String I want to check

```
Hello
Dude
```

My approach is using this regex to match.

```
String strRegExp = "^[Dd][Uu][Dd]";
```

But it does not work. Can´t see where the problem is.
I´m running all this in a simple unit test:

```
@Test
public void testREMatchAtStartOfNewLine()
throws Exception {
    String strRegExp = "^[Dd][Uu][Dd]";
    int flags = RE.REG_MULTILINE;
    String strText ="Hello\nDude";
    RE re = new RE(strRegExp, flags, RESyntax.RE_SYNTAX_PERL5);
    REMatch match = re.getMatch (strText);
    String strResult = "";
    if (match != null) {
        strResult = match.substituteInto ("$0");
    }
    assertEquals("Match at start of new line ", "Dud", strResult);   // FAILS
}
```

Thanks in advance.
edit:
To clarify, I am using following imports:

```
import gnu.regexp.RE;
import gnu.regexp.REMatch;
import gnu.regexp.RESyntax;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you are using GNU Regex library given that the home page has a broken download link? :)

Anyways, it seems that when using `RESyntax.RE_SYNTAX_PERL5` expects `\r\n` as line separator. Replacing `\n` with `\r\n` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what regex you are using but the following works for me:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...

@Test
public void testREMatchAtStartOfNewLine() {
    String strRegExp = ".*\n([Dd][Uu][Dd]).*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strRegExp);
    String strText = "Hello\nDude";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strText);
    assertTrue(matcher.matches());
    assertEquals("Match at start of new line ", "Dud", matcher.group(1)); // WINS
}
```

Notice the `".*"` at the front and end of the pattern.  By default Java regex need to match the entire string so those are necessary.